# Can I determine the class name of an object instance at run-time?

Tags: apex

I'm looking for a way to get the name of an object instance at run-time. Is it possible to to determine the class name (as a string) of an instance? i.e. is there an Apex equivalent of the Java myInstance.getClass().getName() or any tricks to achieve just that?

Comment: String.valueOf(myInstance) will get you pretty close - works with built in classes too...

    class MyClass {}


`System.debug(String.valueOf(new MyClass()));`

`//MyClass:[]`


`System.debug(String.valueOf(new PageReference('')));`

`//System.PageReference[]`

Comment: Yes - thanks, only trouble is with that if someone has overridden the toString() method in the class it may return something other than the class name, i.e. you can't *always* rely on it.

Comment: I thought you owned all the classes :P

Comment: @user320 - lol, yes I do and I know that I *have* overridden toString() (for a good reason too) and that it won't work in my use case.

Comment: @user320 your idea works well unless myInstance has a value of null. How would one work around this?

Comment: If `myInstance` is `null`, I think only you can know what you intended to hand it it. What's your requirement exactly? Could be a good question to ask.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`instanceOf` verifies at runtime whether an object is actually an instance of a class...but you would have to write the conditions to check for them all. Also `getSObjectType` will [describe an sObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm).

Comment: Thanks, actually I've just realised that since I own all of the classes I'm interested in I can implement my own getName() method.

Answer (score 7):

Voting for the idea [Method to get the Type of an Object (also Primitive Type not only SObject)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l9wHAAQ) would be a good long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

From [Trailhead's Apex Recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/apex-recipes/blob/12d5f30665865757ed2b47ca699b546443891c6a/force-app/main/default/classes/Testing%20Recipes/TestHelper.cls), covers Inner Classes as well.

```
/**
     * @description It can be useful to know what the type of an object
     * is at runtime. This is especially useful when you're dynamically
     * instantiating objects in code from the name of a class.
     *
     * I'm not generally a fan of relying on an exception to make logic
     * decisions, but in this case I'll make an exception as this is the
     * cleanest method I've yet found for efficently determining an objects
     * class name that covers edge cases where the object is of an inner class'
     * type.
     *
     * This method parses a TypeException for the true name of a class.
     * It generates the exception by forcing a cast from the Object parameter
     * to DateTime. If no typeException occurs, we know it's a dateTime object.
     * @param obj
     * @return      `String`
     */
    public static String getUnkownObjectType(Object obj) {
        String result = 'DateTime';
        try {
            DateTime typeCheck = (DateTime) obj;
        } catch (System.TypeException expectedTypeException) {
            String message = expectedTypeException.getMessage()
                .substringAfter('Invalid conversion from runtime type ');
            result = message.substringBefore(' to Datetime');
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below:

```
String.valueOf(this).substring(0,String.valueOf(this).indexOf(':'));
```

Sources
 @[pbattisson's Ans](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23998/return-name-of-class-from-instance-of-that-class) 
 @[Matthew's Ans in SF blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wSPIAY#ext-gen52)

Comment: this doesn't return the fully qualified name for inner classes.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't try it for inner class though. Do we have any work around to get the name of inner class? Thanks

Comment: Caveat: The bigger the class, the more CPU is needed for `String.valueOf(this)`