# Get full class name of an inner class instance?

Tags: apex

I have a inner class

```
public class Outer {
   public class Inner {
      ...
   }
}
```

and need to get that running

```
System.assertEquals('Outer.Inner', getClassName(new Outer.Inner()));
```

I found out that you can get the inner class name, but not the outer class:

```
System.assertEquals('Inner', String.valueOf(classInstance).substring(0, String.valueOf(classInstance).indexOf(':'));
```

I could do a SOSL query on all ApexClass' body but that would be somewhat quirky...

Comment: @Phil: Please convert this to an answer so in case nothing else comes I can credit you ;)

Comment: Here's a way to get inner class as well dynamically (but it's a bit ugly): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/384185/7503